# unwanted newline character from Jquery ajax POST

Tags: php, jquery, post

Here is the jquery

```
$("#accountCheck").keyup(function(){

    $.post('accountEmailCheck.php',{value:$(this).val()},function(data){
        $("#emailCheck").val(data);
    });

     $.post('emailEICheck.php',{value:$(this).val()},function(data){

        if (data=='Yes'){ 

                            $("#autoEmail").prop("checked",true);
                        }else{ 

                            $("#autoEmail").prop("checked",false);
                        }
    });
```

Here is the PHP code

```
<?php

include 'sqlconn.php'; //just my sql connection strings

$strResult='';

$getEmailStatus = odbc_exec($live, "SELECT * FROM Accounts WHERE Account = '".$_POST['value']."'");
while(odbc_fetch_array($getEmailStatus)){

$strResult = odbc_result($getEmailStatus,'mailEI');

}

echo trim($strResult);

?>
```

the 'Yes' that comes back has a newline character at the end (the chrome dev tools shows it as like an enter symbol or return) even after I added the trim to the php...

Comment: When you are using ZF or some other framework, you can dimiss the `?>` close tag to avoid spaces on the eof.

Answer (score 4):

Remove the `?>` at the end of your php file.
If you're not going to have any output after the code logic you should not have the `?>` end tag because it could cause unintended whitespace to be outputted that may be after the `?>`.

Comment: seems really counter to coding to not include a closing tag haha even though I trust you that it will work it pains me to take it out, it seems unfinished

Comment: @ScottC it's not counter, it's actually a good practice, when your files contain just PHP code. This is even more important if you start using version control systems such as GIT/SVN, ecc.

Comment: the longest 7 minutes i've witnessed.